# Is there a Fastai vision's unet_learner equivalent in keras?

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, keras

I have implemented Fastai vision's [unet_learner](https://docs.fast.ai/vision.learner.html#unet_learner) successfully to get results.

However, due to hardware compatibility issues, I have been forced to shift to TensorFlow, on reading equivalent for Fastai in TensorFlow I have come across the Keras module.

I have tried searching for the equivalent of [unet_lerner](https://docs.fast.ai/vision.learner.html#unet_learner) in Keras documentation however I have not found any.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Found this library that works as an alternative to fastai vision's unet_leraner classifier:

https://segmentation-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#unet